# CI url error from switching from wamp 2.4 to 2.5

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration, wamp, wampserver

I have:

- Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1 i586
- Apache/2.4.9 (Win32)
- PHP/5.5.12
- MySQL 5.6.17

I updated/reinstalled my wamp server from 2.4 (64 bit) to 2.5 (32 bit) because I need imagick extension and I have that it wont work in 64 bit php.
My urls used to work like this:

> localhost/project/controller_name (without index.php/)

but when I tried to access the pages, it keeps giving a non found error that can only be fixed by adding the index.php. Meaning, they will only work if the url is of the form

> localhost/project/index.php/controller_name

I have tried some answer from some thread i've found in the internet but nothing seemed to work yet. Do you have any idea what do I have to do to make it ignore the index.php part of the url so that my code will still work the way it is?

Comment: `mode_rewrite` in apache enabled? check if it is enabled, its name is `rewrite_module`

Comment: @TomeӾsanS do I have to enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TomeӾsanS's comment solved this. I simply enabled the `rewrite_module` and url is okay without the index.php again.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens from wampserver 2.5. It is a simple problem.
 Here is a solution explained in details:
 http://itutorage.com/article/29/bad-page-redirection-or-wrong-page-redirection-with-wampserver-2-5

Comment: I have already solved "localhost" problem. my problem here is no longer on the part of adding the "localhost" in the url but is on adding/removing the "index.php." project used to work perfectly before the upgrade.